# Shell script to transfer file from Unix to Mainframe data set using Pentaho or Shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, sftp, pentaho, mainframe

I want to transfer a .txt file from Linux Server to Mainframe dataset.

I am using Pentaho to create the file. But Pentaho's SFTP requires a File path and since Mainframe uses filename as File Path, it says directory doesn't exist after successfully connecting to Mainframe host. 
After research, I found that this can be done using Shell Script which can be executed in Pentaho. But I have never done shell scripting before and would appreciate if someone can guide me through it.

Comment: Is the mainframe running the [OpenSSH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ssh/ssh.htm) SFTP daemon or the Dovetailed Technologies' [Co:Z](https://www.dovetail.com/products/sftp.html) SFTP daemon?  The former [does not directly support "classic" mainframe datasets](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.foto100/sftpmvs.htm) while [the latter does](https://www.dovetail.com/docs/sftp/using.html#ds).

Comment: @cschneid, we use Dovetailed daemon and it does have mainframe datasets